# How can I read a JSON with header and body with spring boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

Good morning I have a small query, I am doing a small web service rest with spring boot, the issue is that it is working fine and everything else, as I am doing as follows, receives a parameter and returns a response based on a Stored Procedue in the database:

[image]

But now I have changed the request, and it is including header and body, like the following:

```
{
  "ValidateClient": {
    "Header": {
        "country": "VE",
        "lang": "ES",
        "entity": "TMVE",
        "system": "76",
        "subsystem": "APP",
        "operation": "ValidateClient",
        "timestamp": "2019-10-23T08:48:08.474Z",
        "msgType": "REQUEST"
      },
    "Body": {
      "validateClientRequest": {
        "movil": "04141734272"
      }
   }
}
}
```

Which when executing it gives me an answer of not found the mobile, it is a default response when it cannot read the mobile parameter or it is sent empty

[image]

My Code

Main Class

```
package com.app.validate;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ValidateClientApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ValidateClientApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.app.validate.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.app.validate.dao.ValidateClientAppRepository;
import com.app.validate.entity.DriverBonificados;
import com.app.validate.entity.ResponseVo;

@RestController
public class ValidateClientAppController {

    @Autowired
    private ValidateClientAppRepository dao; 

    @PostMapping(value = "/ValidateClientApp",consumes = "application/json",produces="application/json") 
    public ResponseVo ValidateClient(@RequestBody DriverBonificados driver) {
        //System.out.println(driver.getMovil()); 
        return dao.validarClienteBonifiado(driver.getMovil()); 
    }

}
```

Dao

```
package com.app.validate.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.app.validate.entity.DriverBonificados;
import com.app.validate.entity.ResponseVo;

@Repository
public interface ValidateClientAppRepository extends JpaRepository<DriverBonificados, Integer> {


    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "call ValidacionClienteBonificado(:movil)")
    ResponseVo validarClienteBonifiado(@Param("movil") String pMovil);

}
```

Entity

```
package com.app.validate.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="DriverBonificados")
public class DriverBonificados {

    @Id
    private int id;     
    private String movil;
    private String contador;
    private Date fecha_driver;
    private Date fecha_alta;
    private Date fecha_fin;
    private Date codigo_transaccion;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMovil() {
        return movil;
    }
    public void setMovil(String movil) {
        this.movil = movil;
    }
    public String getContador() {
        return contador;
    }
    public void setContador(String contador) {
        this.contador = contador;
    }
    public Date getFecha_driver() {
        return fecha_driver;
    }
    public void setFecha_driver(Date fecha_driver) {
        this.fecha_driver = fecha_driver;
    }
    public Date getFecha_alta() {
        return fecha_alta;
    }
    public void setFecha_alta(Date fecha_alta) {
        this.fecha_alta = fecha_alta;
    }
    public Date getFecha_fin() {
        return fecha_fin;
    }
    public void setFecha_fin(Date fecha_fin) {
        this.fecha_fin = fecha_fin;
    }
    public Date getCodigo_transaccion() {
        return codigo_transaccion;
    }
    public void setCodigo_transaccion(Date codigo_transaccion) {
        this.codigo_transaccion = codigo_transaccion;
    }

}
```

Interface Response Stored Procedue

```
package com.app.validate.entity;

public interface ResponseVo {

    String getCode();
    String getResult();
}
```

[image]

How could you do to read the Json with header and body? I'm new to spring boot

**UPDATE**

According to what Silverfang said, I created the classes said by him, but I get an error that I describe next:

BodyRequest.java

```
 public class BodyRequest {

    private String validateClientRequest;
    private String movil;

    public String getValidateClientRequest() {
        return validateClientRequest;
    }
    public void setValidateClientRequest(String validateClientRequest) {
        this.validateClientRequest = validateClientRequest;
    }
    public String getMovil() {
        return movil;
    }
    public void setMovil(String movil) {
        this.movil = movil;
    }

}
```

HeaderRequest.java

```
package com.app.validate.controller;

import java.util.Date;

public class HeaderRequest {

    private String country;
    private String lang;
    private String entity;
    private String system;
    private String subsystem;
    private String operation;
    private Date timestamp;
    private String msgType;
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }
    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }
    public String getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
    public void setEntity(String entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
    public String getSystem() {
        return system;
    }
    public void setSystem(String system) {
        this.system = system;
    }
    public String getSubsystem() {
        return subsystem;
    }
    public void setSubsystem(String subsystem) {
        this.subsystem = subsystem;
    }
    public String getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }
    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public String getMsgType() {
        return msgType;
    }
    public void setMsgType(String msgType) {
        this.msgType = msgType;
    }

}
```

RequestBodyDemo.java

```
package com.app.validate.controller;

public class RequestBodyDemo {

    private ValidateClientRequest ValidateClient;

    public ValidateClientRequest getValidateClient() {
        return ValidateClient;
    }

    public void setValidateClient(ValidateClientRequest validateClient) {
        ValidateClient = validateClient;
    }

}
```

ValidateClientRequest

```
package com.app.validate.controller;

public class ValidateClientRequest {

    private BodyRequest Body;
    private HeaderRequest Header;

    public BodyRequest getBody() {
        return Body;
    }
    public void setBody(BodyRequest body) {
        Body = body;
    }
    public HeaderRequest getHeader() {
        return Header;
    }
    public void setHeader(HeaderRequest header) {
        Header = header;
    }

}
```

My Controller (Update)

```
package com.app.validate.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.app.validate.dao.ValidateClientAppRepository;
import com.app.validate.entity.DriverBonificados;
import com.app.validate.entity.ResponseVo;

@RestController
public class ValidateClientAppController {

    @Autowired
    private ValidateClientAppRepository dao; 

    @PostMapping(value = "/ValidateClientApp",consumes = "application/json",produces="application/json") 
    public ResponseVo ValidateClient(@RequestBody  RequestBodyDemo req) {
        System.out.println(req.getValidateClient().getBody().getMovil());

        return dao.validarClienteBonifiado(req.getValidateClient().getBody().getMovil()); 
    }

}
```

The error I get:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you have changed the request format and now want the same request body to work for the same controller.

I think you were trying to add the fields to the header. What you are doing here is not the right way to do it. It should goes to `header section` rather than in the `body section` of the Postman app. But doing so, you will have to specify these header separately as these are custom headers which will be a lot of work.

`Answer to your question`

Going by what you were trying to do. Since now you have changed the request body. You will have to make changes in the controller class too.  Now it will require three classes If you want to do it in a modular way.

The first class will be BodyRequest.java

```
private string validateClientRequest;
private string movil;
```

The next class will be HeaderRequest.java

```
private string country;
private string lang;
private string entity;
private string system;
private string subsystem;
private string operation;
private Date timestamp;
private string msgType;
```

Next class will be ValidateClientRequest.java

```
private HeaderRequest Header;
private BodyRequest Body;
```

Now for the RequestBodyDemo class;

```
private ValidateClientRequest ValidateClient;
```

Note : Use appropriate `Getter` and `setter` along with `@JsonProperty` if you are masking the input request data.

Once these things are done. In your controller Instead of using Entity in `@RequestBody` Use the class `RequestBodyDemo`. Once that is done. Just try printing the values just to check whether you are getting them right or not. Then use `getter` for fetching any value that you need.

Edit :

```
  public ResponseVo ValidateClient(@RequestBody  RequestBodyDemo req) {
        System.out.println(req.getValidateClient().getBodyrequest().getMovil()); 

        return dao.validarClienteBonifiado(req.getValidateClient().getBodyrequest().getMovil()); 
    }
```

Note : Use appropriate getter method here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have the question of how the final answer would be, that is, in my controller how could I get the mobile parameter, with the get method in the RequestBodyDemo class? when using the get method, the mobile property option does not appear

Comment: Do it like this first `requestBodyDemo.getValidateClientRequest().getBodyRequest().getmovil()` It will give you movil parameter that you have passed in the request body

Comment: Could you put the code in the controller part as you would? It's giving me java.lang.NullPointerException: null error, and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Update my question, because I get an error with your solution

Comment: Hey if you still didn't get it Here is the demo project that I have made for you You can check for any mistakes that you have been doing. On other note my above answer is not the exact answer. you will have to change the getter and setter and along with the variable names to match yours. Here is the link to my demo Project. https://github.com/1Silverfang1/demo-validate-client Ping me if you got your answer

Comment: Just make a post request to /validate with your json and Although it will not return anything but you will be able to see the values on the console

Comment: I already understood how it works, and I tried it and everything well, thank you very much for your help, I will mark your answer as correct :)